# Any way to get on which member C++20 defaulted comparison failed?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Often I write test expectations on structs/classes that have either defaulted `<=>` or defaulted `==`.

Issue is that when expectation fails I have no idea what member caused the failure(usually I use `EXPECT_EQ` so `==` returned `false`). Reason for this is that `<=>` / `==` are basically compiler generated black boxes.

I know C++ has no reflection, but is there maybe some hack/trick to get the mismatch between two instances?

Just to be clear here is brief example(in real code often data is much more complex and not obvious from looking at values where mismatch is):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    int x;
    int y;
    bool operator == (const A& ) const = default;
};

struct B {
    A a;
    int z;
    bool operator == (const B& ) const = default;
};

int main() {
    B b1{.a{.x=1, .y=2}, .z{3}};
    B b2{.a{.x=1, .y=8472}, .z{3}};
    std::cout << (b1 == b2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "missmatch at member" /*magic missing*/ <<  std::endl;
}
```

I know protobuf has reflection and that I can decorate my structs with metadata using Boost.Describe, this question is about purely ISO C++ solution without any changes to structs.

Also I know I can manually compare members, that is what now I do when I hit this issue(or just look at values of structs), but I would like to "automate" this process.

Comment: No, Not except following debugger-break-point manually.

Comment: Your shown classes respect [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)'s constraints, so you might transform them in tuple, and know which fields mismatch.